# a book for introduction into integral, sigma, telescoping series

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, definite-integrals, book-recommendation

I needed to learn definite and indefinite integrals and their related lessons so I started an online course for that and after one session I understood that having a fairly good knowledge about sigma and telescoping series was one of its prerequisites.
What I need is a book or reference or course for starting to learn integral, sigma and other things that may put me in trouble while learning integral.

Comment: A lot more specific information than this is needed, otherwise anyone reading your question is simply going to wonder why don't you consult any of the thousands of calculus texts that have been published since the mid 1800s. Either cite the specific course you're taking (e.g. provide the web page with the course syllabus), or explain -- giving specific topics and such -- why a standard calculus text lacks what you are looking for.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro well the problem is that the course Im taking is not in english and you may have problems understanding it but I will try to find the nearest english book to it.

Comment: If there is a web page with the contents (syllabus, etc.), then I (and others) can use web browsers to translate the web page.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro after some research I found out the syllabus of the course Im taking is very near to the book of james stewart "calculus concepts and contexts 2nd edition" and when I took a look at the integral part I still have the problems mentioned in the main question.